# Python Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, anaconda

Using Anaconda, Python has a problem whenever I import Pandas, Numpy, Matplotlib, etc.:

```
python.exe - Ordinal Not Found

The ordinal 242 could not be located in the dynamic link library

C:\Programs\Anaconda\pkgs\mkl-2019.1-144\Library\bin\mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

This notification pops up in a dialog box. I also get the following error in the console itself:

```
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

The issue does not occur when importing modules from the standard library (e.g. re, datetime). It happens when I use any version of Python (e.g. iPython, Jupyter Notebook, python.exe).

The .dll itself is located in the place that it's looking, so I honestly have no idea what the issue is. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling to no avail, and have scoured the Internet for assistance without finding any answers. Please help!

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to use the debugger in `pycharm`.  I updated my `conda` version and then updated package `mkl` in the corresponding virtual environment.  The problem went away.

Answer (score 11):

```
pip uninstall numpy
pip install numpy
```

it's work for me,uninstall conda environment package "numpy" and reinstall latest edition.

Comment: Thanks -- this worked for me. Windows 10, using the Anaconda terminal...

Comment: for anaconda, isn't it recommended to use `conda` to un/install, instead of `pip`?  Or is using `pip` important here?

Answer (score 7):

It's known DLL version conflict.
There is workaround described in anaconda's docs: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/troubleshooting.html#numpy-mkl-library-load-failed

On windows, just run `set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1` in command prompt before using python.