# Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll

Tags: python, dll, cx-freeze, intel-mkl

Previously I asked a similar question: [cx_Freeze unable fo find mkl: MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57493584/cx-freeze-unable-fo-find-mkl-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll)

But now I have a subtle difference. I want to run the program without installing anaconda, just within a `cmd.exe` terminal, but it seems I am doing something wrong or that it is not possible.

After generating my application with `python setup.py bdist_msi` using `cx-freeze`, I am able to install and then run it within an anaconda environment, but if I simply open a `cmd.exe` terminal and run it, I get

```
INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. mkl_intel_thread.dll.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll.
```

However, when running

```
where  mkl_intel_thread.dll
```

the dll is found, so I think this means it's registered in the system (I am more used to use Linux, so may be I am wrong).

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: The issue causing `Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll` has been solved in cx_Freeze 6.7, see https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/739

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe another DLL necessary for MKL, such as `libiomp5md.dll` for example, is missing and causes the error. See [Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.dll on python executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54337644/8516269), my answer there and its comments.

If this still does not solve your problem, try to manually copy other DLLs from the anaconda environment's library path into the app installation directory and its `lib` subdirectory. Once you have found which dependency is missing, you can use the `include_files` option of cx_Freeze to automatize this step in the setup (as you know).

Another possible issue would be that you have an incompatible version of MKL installed on your system and that the frozen application finds this wrong one, but this is unlikely unless you have a 32-bit Python installation on a 64-bit system or have installed the application on another system.

EDIT:

It could still also simply be that the frozen application does not find `mkl_intel_thread.dll` although `where` finds it. `where` looks in the system search path given by the `PATH` environment variable, while Python looks in the modules search path given by `sys.path`, which usually does not include the content of `PATH`, see [Where is Python's sys.path initialized from?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/897792/8516269) But on Windows there is a fallback mechanism for registered DLLs (I don't know how it works). Anyway, one should not rely on this fallback as soon as one intends to install and run the application on another system, because the necessary DLL may not be installed there. Thus the necessary dependencies should always be included in the installation directory.

Comment: That was it!, `libiomp5md.dll` although now the contents of my package are not copying correctly to `lib`/

Comment: It was a missing `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Thank you! Adding the path to Intel OpenMP's `libiomp5md.dll` - in addition to previously adding the path to `mkl_rt.dll` - cured the `mkl_intel_thread.dll` load issue for me in my Python environment.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I faced the same error in python3.7 . I did not have the option of moving Dll,  I Solved the problem by just doing.

```
conda install cython
```

After the cython install all dll's were in proper place.

Answer (score 1):

As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/56186333/977566 I renamed c:\windows\system32\libiomp5md.dll to .bak and that fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

> set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1;

will solve all your problems

Answer (score 0):

For this, it is enough to get the full version of visual c++ program and delete anaconda and folders related to anaconda such as `.anaconda` or `.conda` or `.matplotlib` or `AppData/anaconda` and ... and then install it again
Of course, don't forget that all Intel services must be active
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170