# getting error mkl_intel_thread.1.dll was not found in executing.exe

Tags: python, tkinter

Trying to make an .exe but unable to run the same getting error: I am using anaconda env in pycharm
mkl_intel_thread.1.dll was not found

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57567892/11106801) question looks similar to your one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this renaming the file path

c:\windows\system32\libiomp5md.dll to .bak and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Changing/deleting stuff inside `system32` is very dangerous. If you know what your fix does, please add it to your answer.