# Python Program Exe is not running after packaging it with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I packaged my python program (that was build with Tkinter interface) with Pyinstaller. Everything was installed and packed successfully, however, when I am trying to open application in the dist folder nothing happens. Windows opens command prompt window and closes it within 2-3 sec, and doesn't open the program itself.
Does anybody ever had this issue? I checked Google and haven't found smth similar issue. It doesn't show any errors, it just opens command prompt and closes it immediately and doesn't run the program. However the program runs without any problems in Python without pyinstaller's packed exe file.
I tried to open it with command prompt and it showed me the following:

```
INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. 
mkl_intel_thread.1.dll.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.1.dll.
```

I tried `set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1` and installing cython as well, as it was recommended in another stackoverflow post. But it still doesn't work:(

Comment: Try to open a command line and run the .exe file from within the terminal (or just drag it into the terminal) then you will be able to see the error.

Comment: There are a few existing questions about that error. Please show us what existing solutions you've tried, so that we don't show you a post you've already looked at. For instance, did you try any of the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453060/python-intel-mkl-fatal-error-cannot-load-mkl-intel-thread-dll)?

Comment: Yes, just did it. It shows: INTEL MKL ERROR: The specified module could not be found. 
mkl_intel_thread.1.dll.
Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: Cannot load mkl_intel_thread.1.dll. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this MKL FATAL ERROR

Comment: Yes, I did set CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1, still doesn't work :(